# Exact Time Difference Between two Salesforce Time difference field

Tags: formula-field

I'm trying to create an SF formula field in which we going to return the difference between my two-time field as Start time and End time. I know one approach to calculate the difference showing it as (End_Time__c   -  Start_Time__c )/ 3600000. But the issue with this as it's not giving exactly the difference of time in a minute.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Choose the output data type for your formula field to number with decimal 0.

The formula you used will give you the output in hours. As the start_time__c and end_time__c are both of TIME data type-

> example- start time= 1 AM end time= 3 AM
>
> so the general difference between 2 fields will be 7200000
> milliseconds and
>
> to convert that to seconds divide 7200000 milliseconds by 1000 = gives
> 7200 seconds
>
> to convert that to minutes divide 7200 seconds by 60 = gives 120
> minutes
>
> and if you want to convert that to hours divide 120 minutes by 24 =
> gives 2 hours.

so the formula for your query to get the result in minutes will be

```
(End_Time__c - Start_Time__c )/ 60000
```

Hope, this solves your query.

Cheers